# CD4013 cannot drive Mosfet

Tags: mosfet, flipflop

General Circuit information :

1. Function/Purpose: After the user press a tactile and hold for 6 seconds the circuit latches and turns on the mosfet to in turn turn on the power for a system
2. Power source : 4 X AA batteries 6.8V - 5V

I've tested this circuit first in a simulation application which verified that the Circuit will turn on after 6 seconds, then after building the exact circuit it worked as expected with no problem.
[image]

Now after replacing some components to a smaller alternative, the circuit now latches after 3 seconds and the output from the CD4013 which goes into the gate of the N-channel Mosfet which drives the power of circuit immediately shuts down , by playing around with the resistor 10R-470R (gate resistor) and pull-down and the pull-down resistors I am able to prevent the shutdown and get a good 4.5V-5V at the gate of N-channel, but the P-channel at best at its gate would get a 1.8V-3V at gate which seems to be not enough to close the P-channel. So now it's like a pendulum if I try to ease out the pull up at the P-channel gate the CD4013 shuts down and otherwise the p-channel fails to close.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: That circuit should work. What is the load driven by Q1? Is that dropping the VBATT with the extra load and causing problems? Try it with no load. R9 is not even necessary.

Comment: Q1 should switche a load of maximum 500mA from the battery. I will try the circuit without on Q1 and let you know, hopefully we find the culprit. I just left work (12 am atm), so hopefully you stay with me tomorrow.